# ADF: How to avoid hiding table's Column from view Menu

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I face some problems on my ADF application.

How to avoid hiding table's Column from view Menu[image]

On the image above how can i avoid that the user hidding "Empno" column?

May be somebody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the af:column of the empno set the showRequiered property to true. This prevents hiding the column.

Comment: Perfect! Is there a way to remove the "*"?